# Can I sort a vector to match the sorting of an unordered_map?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, hash, unordered-map

Can I sort a `vector` so that it will match the sorting of an `unordered_map`? I want to iterate over the `unordered_map` and if I could only iterate each container once to find their intersection, rather than having to search for each key.

So for example, given an `unordered_map` containing:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Which is hashed into this order:

> 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 7, 8, 6, 9

I'd like if given a `vector` of:

> 1, 2, 3, 4

I could somehow distill the sorting of the `unordered_map` for use in sorting the `vector` so it would sort into:

> 1, 3, 4, 2

Is there a way to accomplish this? I notice that `unordered_map` does provide it's [`hash_function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/hash_function), can I use this?

Comment: A `unordered_map` doesn't have any sort of sorting.  It is *unordered*

Comment: Not in a portable way. You might be able to match a single library implementation, but it's too dangerous.

Comment: @NathanOliver You can still try to match the order obtained when iterating through begin()/end(). Misguided as that might be.

Comment: Also, even if you could do it, sorting a vector is a O(NLogN) operation, so given enough data, it would be actually slower than doing the lookups in O(N) time.

Comment: @Frank Sure, you could go by how it is ordered but there is no guarantee that even the same set of elements has the same order.  For instance [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/149d27e11d806bed) shows the same elements get arranged differently depending on the order they were inserted.

Comment: @Frank You *can* try, and even manage to match a single library implementation *and a fixed element insertion order*. The question is whether you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments correctly state, there is no even remotely portable way of matching sorting on `unordered_map`. So, sorting is unspecified.

However, in the land of unspecified, sometimes for various reasons we can be cool with whatever *our implementation* does, even if unspecified and non-portable. So, could someone look into your map implementation and use the determinism it has there on the vector?

The problem with `unordered_map` is that it's a hash. Every element inserted into it will be hashed, with hash (mapped to the key space) used as an index in internal array. This looks promising, and it would be promising if not for collision. In case of key collision, the elements are put into the collision list, and this list is not sorted at all. So the order of iteration over collision would be determined by the order of inserts (reverse or direct). Because of that, absent information of order of inserts, it would not be possible to mimic the order of the `unordered_map`, even for specific implementation.